# Text as block on Kali Linux Rolling after apt-get upgrade

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, fonts, theme

I just installed Kali Linux Rolling and I run apt-get upgrade. When it finished on the tweak tool on the appearance tab in the cursor option, I get this text "Adwaita [][][][][][][][][]" instead of "Adwaita (Default)".

Also on the system monitor on the processes tab, on the memory column, on the process that ram status is "N/A" I get this text again "[][][]".

[image]

Comment: Looks like filesystem corruption, have you checked that?

Comment: I have format my dist for two time and then i install again the kali linux rolling. Before i run apt-get upgrade everything is alright but when the apt-get upgrade process fished i get this text error.

Comment: Assuming that that was correctly displayed before the upgrade, the other thing it might be a font update to a font that doesn't have specific code-points that the Adwaita description is using.

Comment: So what i have to do?

Answer (score 6):

I got mine fixed by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-cantarell
```

Comment: This worked, saved me from a full reinstall. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use:

1. apt-get autoremove fonts-cantarell
2. apt-get install fonts-cantarell (cursor changed back at this point)
3. shutdown -r now

After restart even the lock screen went from boxes back to what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Start Kali in recovery mode and try:

```
# apt-get install --reinstall fonts-cantarell
# shutdown -r now
```

those worked for me